# left_join breaking sf

Tags: r, sf

Trying to add a data column to a simplefeatures point object using dplyr::left_join, but it appears to drop the sf class:

```
class(sf)
[1] "sf"        "data.frame"
class(df)
[1] "tbl_df"    "tbl"    "data.frame"

eg <- left_join(sf, df, by = 'common_col')

class(eg)
[1] "data.frame"
```

same thing happens when `df` is just a plain data frame. I can fix it easily enough with

```
eg <- st_as_sf(eg)
```

but this feels like an unnecessary extra step. Am I making poor function choices for what I'm trying to do, or is this an actual bug?

Comment: `sf` now defines a method for `*_join` (and `merge`). Install from [Github](https://github.com/edzer/sfr).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until this gets changed you might want to define a `left_join` method for `sf` classes that does the conversion for you:

```
left_join.sf =
function(x,y,by=NULL,copy=FALSE,suffix=c(".x",".y"),...){
ret = NextMethod("left_join")
st_as_sf(ret)
}
```

Example: before:

```
> nc = st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
> newdata = data.frame(CRESS_ID=1:100,Z=runif(100))
> nc2 = left_join(nc, newdata)
Joining, by = "CRESS_ID"
> class(nc2)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Then with `left_join.sf`, just using `left_join(...)` does:

```
> nc2 = left_join(nc, newdata)
Joining, by = "CRESS_ID"
> class(nc2)
[1] "sf"         "data.frame"
```

If you look at the source for what `left_join` does on a plain R data frame, you'll see it follows the same pattern - the actual join is done on a `tbl` version of `x`, and then its converted back to a data frame:

```
> dplyr:::left_join.data.frame
function (x, y, by = NULL, copy = FALSE, ...) 
{
    as.data.frame(left_join(tbl_df(x), y, by = by, copy = copy, 
        ...))
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks. I defined a similar method for base::merge too, although I feel like I'm stepping way out of my comfort zone...